# Azure - Basic App Comunication c# vs 2012

Tags: c#, azure, tcp, worker

I have to write an application with azure in c# that:

has a worker role comparing gps information
stores user profile information

and can get and set both of these from user device.

for example what i want is for my device to periodically upload its gps co-ordinates to the worker by opening a connection with the worker role, authenticate the user, allow saving the gps co -ordibates over any existing co-ordinates for this user. Also or as a separate worker i don't know, i need the worker role to be checking and performing calculations on the gps' of all devices. Which at certain points would then push the some information down to a particular device.

What i want doesnt seem difficult but finding just a simple example of a tcp message from  a device to an azure service ive spent hours looking its the comunications between devices that im not understanding

Comment: Azure is nothing more than scalable infrastructure-as-a-service.  Using it doesn't invalidate all the conventional methods of making TCP connections - you just have to take a couple of extra steps get the right ports open and make your service properly scalable.  Are you able to develop tcp messaging in a non-Azure environment to begin with?

Comment: mellamokb the Wise, im in my final year of university and have only just been introduced to sockets and have used udp (but for java). Strange considering untill the final year for programming style modules we only every used c# really. how ever after looking at @Ondrej Tucny comment is what i actually want a hosted web service? and why is this not achievable via azure? or is it easier/harder? where if this is the case can i start looking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP programming with Azure is possible, but not practical if you need the TCP endpoint available at all times. A TCP endpoint cannot remain inactive for long periods of time in Azure.

You can certainly use Web Services as Ondrej suggests. Or you can also use Azure Queues.  I wrote a [blog about scaling with Azure Queues](http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2012/12/27/scalable-distributed-workload-with-azure-queues.aspx). It's a message based solution that runs on top of REST calls.

What I am not clear about is your need to reach out to all the devices from Azure directly. Unless I misunderstood your scenario, you want an Azure role to "connect" to all existing devices, get data from them, perform some calculation in Azure, then push back the data to a device? This seems rather hard to do and error prone if your devices are not accessible - if your GPS devices register with the worker roles, and can be accessed by public DNS I guess you could do that. But personally I would lean towards a solution that only pushes data from the device into the cloud; it should be much easier that way.  What kind of devices are you referring to? And what are you trying to do?

Comment: thank you both @Herve Roggero @, is my basic understanding wrong? I want to: gps from lots of portable devices say every 2 minutes associate them with a user name and some basic info so they can be identified. some process should work out when two devices get within a certain distance of each other and then the devices start sending more accurate and frequent gps information and if the devices get within 10 metres for example the devices should be notified of each others positions :)

Comment: Oh... I see. I would push the data through queues because it's very easy with REST. Then I would also have an Azure Table for each device that contains the list of users/devices that are nearby. So the device can broadcast its location at all times through the queue (or a few queues - see blog I posted in my original response), and check the Azure Table as needed. The worker role would simply update the Azure Table with the list of nearby devices. You can have as many azure tables as you want; they scale automatically and Azure Tables are cheap.